# If not value (options page) then

Tags: php, wordpress, dashboard

I'm using the following code to activate an function whenever the functions is activated with a checkbox on my WordPress options page:

```php
$option_value = get_option('options_table');
if ( isset( $option_value['options_value']) && $option_value['options_value'] == 1  ) { 
     function () {
          echo 'test';
     }
}
```

Now I want to activate the function whenever the `option_value` is empty and tried using

```php
$option_value = get_option('options_table');
if ( isset( $option_value['options_value']) && $option_value['options_value'] !== 1  ) { 
     function () {
          echo 'test';
     }
}
```

As far as I know the `!==` part means 'Not equal' but my code isn't working and can't seem to figure out why not. Any pointers?

Comment: It is `!=` for not-equal. Read  the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well... I've deleted the seccond part and it seems to be working but I'm not sure why.

```
if ( isset( $option_value['options_value']) !== 1  ) { 
     function () {
          echo 'test';
     }
}
```